# $http Authentication for an Ionic App with a Sails.js backend

Tags: javascript, sails.js, ionic-framework

I have a mobile application:

Front end - Ionic framework

Back-end - Sails.js API

I need help to setup the Ionic application, and create a registration and login flow for:

1. Username / Password registration & login
2. Setup the Sails.js backend with the User controller
3. Tie them together so that users can create accounts and login.

Could anyone point me in the right direction. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

This is my sign-in template

```
<script id="templates/sign-in.html" type="text/ng-template">
    < ion - view > < div class = "bar bar-header bar-positive" > < h1 class = "title" > Sign - In < /h1>
            </div > < ion - content style = "margin-top:40px !important" > < div class = "list list-inset" > < label id = "acc"
    class = "item item-input" > < input type = "text"
    ng - model = "user.account"
    placeholder = "Account" > < /label>
                    <label id="user" class="item item-input">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="user.user" placeholder="Username">
                    </label >

    < label id = "pass"
    class = "item item-input" > < input type = "password"
    ng - model = "user.password"
    placeholder = "Password" > < /label>
                </div > < div class = "padding" > < button class = "button button-block button-positive"
    ng - click = "signIn(user)" >
        Sign - In < /button>
                </div > < div id = "error"
    style = "color:#a94442;"
    class = "item item-divider" >

    < /div>
            </ion - content > < /ion-view>
</script>
```

On ng-click call i have the following function to call

```
$scope.signIn = function signIn(user) {
if (user) {
    var ath = user.account + ',' + user.user + ',' + user.password;
    var url = "http://youradress.com/you";
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Credentials': ath
        }
    };
    $http.get(url, config).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data.indexOf("Permission") > -1) {
            $state.go('devices-list')
        } else {
            error = document.getElementById("error");
            error.innerHTML = "Unable to logged in! Check Credentials";
        }
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        error = document.getElementById("error");
        error.innerHTML = "Unable to logged in! Check Internet"
    });
  }
 }
```